# Regex to match the beginning and the end of a string in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract a certain like of string using Regex in Java. I currently have this pattern:

```
pattern = "^\\a.+\\sed$\n";
```

Supposed to match on a string that starts with "a" and ends with "sed". This is not working. Did I miss something ?

Removed the \n line at the end of the pattern and replaced it with a "$": 
Still doesn't get a match. The regex looks legit from my side.

What I want to extract is the "a sed" from the temp string.

```
String temp = "afsgdhgd gfgshfdgadh a sed afdsgdhgdsfgdfagdfhh";
                pattern = "(?s)^a.*sed$";
                       pr = Pattern.compile(pattern);

                math = pr.matcher(temp);
```

Comment: is "a sed" exactly what you looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

You want to match `a sed`, so you can use `a\\s+sed` if there is only whitespace between `a` and `sed`:

```
String s = "afsgdhgd gfgshfdgadh a sed afdsgdhgdsfgdfagdfhh";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a\\s+sed");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ierVut)

Now, **if there can be *anything* between `a` and `sed`**, use a tempered greedy token:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)a(?:(?!a|sed).)*sed");
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [another IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/kihzQx).

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The main problem with your regex is the `\n` at the end. `$` is the end of string, and you try to match one more character after a string end, which is impossible. Also, `\\s` matches a whitespace symbol, but you need a literal `s`.

You need to remove `\\`s and `\n` and make `.` match a newline, and also it is advisbale to use `*` quantifier to allow 0 symbols in-between:

```
pattern = "(?s)^a.*sed$";
```

**[See the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lY3qD0/1)**

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `a` - a literal `a`
- `.*` - 0 or more any characters (since `(?s)` modifier makes a `.` match any character including a newline)
- `sed` - a literal letter sequence `sed`
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Please check my update. I think one of the solutions should work for you.

Comment: Will this work if there is a tab or only spaces? Thank you! Doesn't a general regex to match "beginning of character" and "end of character" exist?

Comment: No idea what solution you refer to. `\s` matches *any whitespace* including tabs, spaces, newlines. Beginning and end of character? No, nothing like that exists, but I suspect you are talking about `\\b`, a word boundary: `\\bsed\\b` will match `sed` in `a sed tool`, but won't match it in `seduce`. As for the tempered greedy token solution, `.` will match *any character* (including newline symbols) since I have used `(?s)` DOTALL modifier.

Answer (score 1):

Your `temp` string cannot match the pattern `(?s)^a.*sed$`, because this pattern says that your `temp` string **must begin** with the character **a** and **end with** the sequence **sed**, which is not the case. Your string has trailing characters after the "sed" sequence.
If you only want to extract that *a...sed* portion of the whole string, try using the unanchored pattern "a.*sed" and use the `find()` method of the `Matcher class`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a.*sed");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(temp);
if (m.find())
{
    System.out.println("Found string "+m.group());
    System.out.println("From "+m.start()+" to "+m.end());
}
```